# Mongodb not able to connect database

Tags: mongodb

I am facing a weird problem. I have created a database and a couple of collections. They are accessed by drivers and running smooth in production. When I created the production environment, I created a user with admin privilege and the same credentials used in connection string by all drivers. I observed that the system.users collection had an entry for the user I created. But when I started using Replica Sets, it was failing with auth = true. Since the same key was not configured in the config, so I removed auth = true in config file but continued using same credentials to connect to the database from the drivers.

Now there are no user entries in the database. I dont know how it vanished. Moreoever, the drivers are still using the same credentials to connect to the database. Without using username/pwd in connectionstring, I am unable to connect to db (from the drivers). I am suprised that that works.

But the bigger problem I'm having is that whenever I create a new database and create a collection in it, I am able to access it on mongoshell, but I am unable to connect to it from the drivers which use connectionstring credentials. This constraint forces me to create all collections in the same database.

How do I resolve the issue, does it have anything to do with mongod.lock?? I cant afford to take down the production environment even for a minute..

Comment: Did you follow these docs when setting up the authentication for ReplicaSets:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#inter-process-auth-key-file

Comment: Are you running mongo-shell on the same host as MongoD is running and the application is running on a remote host? Also after changing the auth = true in the config file, did you restart the MongoD instances?

Comment: @Sammaye I edited the posting for OP. Would you mind removing the "paragraphs help..." comment. It has outlived its useful life. :)